# Exclude Values, including null, using Query Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, definition-query

I'm looking to exclude any streams that have values of "NULL" or "NP" using an SQL query in ArcGIS 10.2.

I've tried expressions like:

`WTR_NM NOT (NULL, NP)`

WTR_MN is the Field Name and I'm trying to remove the unnamed streams.

Comment: What product are you using? There are several that refer to themselves as 'Query Builder' (Oracle, Microsoft, etc). In that context what is NP?

Comment: This is in ArcMap 10.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL syntax for excluding nulls is slightly different from what is used to exclude normal values. The following should work to my knowledge:

```
WTR_NM IS NOT NULL AND WTR_NM <> 'NP'
```

This of course assumes that the NULL values are actually nulls, and not string values simply holding the word "NULL". It's counter-intuitive but the two types are different.

Comment: @Dameron As an aside, sometimes data can be pretty dirty when it comes to nulls. I frequently see cases where some values are truly <null> while others are simply blank (''). It's a good idea to verify this in your data, otherwise you might want to add a third condition to check for blanks as well - `WTR_NM IS NOT NULL AND (WTR_NM <> 'NP' OR WTR_NM <> ''`. Alternatively, `WTR_NM IS NOT NULL AND WTR_NM NOT IN ('NP', '')`.